# How do you resolve Google Play services error in Android 6+?

Tags: android, google-play-services

As I am using Firebase, I need to check that I have a supported version of Google Play Services on app startup. GooglePlayServicesUtil is deprecated. So, I'm using the new shiny GoogleApiAvailability api, and I can detect if an upgrade is needed.

But when I use the [GoogleApiAvailability.getErrorDialog](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/GoogleApiAvailability.html#getErrorDialog(android.app.Activity,%20int,%20int,%20android.content.DialogInterface.OnCancelListener)) is does not launch the required intent. It doesn't do anything. A trawl of the internet does not reveal any useful code samples. Ideally, I would like to write my own custom dialog and launch the pendingIntent but this has also been elusive. My code:

```
    final GoogleApiAvailability googleAPI = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
    final int resultCode = googleAPI.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if (resultCode == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        if (isOnline()) {
            app.init(this, this);
        }
    } else {
            switch (resultCode) {
                case SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED:
                    Dialog updateDialog = googleAPI.getErrorDialog(this, resultCode, PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST, mOnCancelFinishApp);
                    updateDialog.setOnDismissListener(mOnDismissFinishApp);
                    updateDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                    updateDialog.show();
                    ...
```

Update: My gradle has these dependencies

```
.....
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    compile('com.microsoft.aad:adal:2.0.1-alpha') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    }
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.0.0'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:answers:1.3.12@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.7@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:10.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.0'
    provided 'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        // These docs use an open ended version so that our plugin
        // can be updated quickly in response to Android tooling updates

        // We recommend changing it to the latest version from our changelog:
        // https://docs.fabric.io/android/changelog.html#fabric-gradle-plugin
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
```

Comment: please update your gradle file

Comment: @YogeshBorhade i have included dependencies from my gradle file.

Comment: Please post your gradle file

Comment: `:play-services-location:` 2 times

Answer (score 0):

Please check GooglePlayServices Available or not

```
Dialog errorDialog;

private boolean checkPlayServices() {

        GoogleApiAvailability googleApiAvailability = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();

        int resultCode = googleApiAvailability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);

        if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            if (googleApiAvailability.isUserResolvableError(resultCode)) {

                if (errorDialog == null) {
                    errorDialog = googleApiAvailability.getErrorDialog(this, resultCode, 2404);
                    errorDialog.setCancelable(false);
                }

                if (!errorDialog.isShowing())
                    errorDialog.show();

            }
        }

        return resultCode == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS;
    }
```

Comment: This appears to be copied from other answers I have seen and does not work for Marshmallow.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with these changes:

```
....
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }


buildscript {
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

dependencies {
    // These docs use an open ended version so that our plugin
    // can be updated quickly in response to Android tooling updates

    // We recommend changing it to the latest version from our changelog:
    // https://docs.fabric.io/android/changelog.html#fabric-gradle-plugin
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
 }
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

compile('com.microsoft.aad:adal:2.0.1-alpha') {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support'
}
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.0.0'
compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:answers:1.3.12@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.7@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:10.0.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.0'
provided 'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```